# Proguard : ignore library proguard errors

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I am optimizing my proguard configuration and I am still keeping some class names that are not compulsory.

After intensive reflection I finally find why.
My class implements `Parcelable` and I use some libraries which use this proguard configuration:

```
# Needed for Parcelable/SafeParcelable Creators to not get stripped
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

which seems to be keep the names of the class and the `CREATOR` field.
I think that just the `CREATOR` field is really required as it is possible to read in the official `proguard-android-optimize.txt` proguard file:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

As I am not the owner of the library, I cannot change it. Is there a way to override their proguard configuration file ? (which may be included with the `consumerProguardFiles` gradle keyword)

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came to a solution concerning `proguard-android-optimize.txt`.

In AndroidStudio, you have access to `proguard-android-optimize.txt` (`⌘↑O` on mac, or `control + shift + N` for windows/linux). Just copy the file content, and paste it to your project without the rules you want to remove. Finally use it as your own proguardFiles.

replace

> proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

with

> proguardFiles 'proguard-android-optimize.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro'

Be aware that it is at your own risk and that you won't have the optimization from the latest embedded proguard files.

Concerning the `consumerProguardFiles` you have no choice to do pull request to them if you can, or ask for an evolve if you can contact the library author.